# On checkbox status checked can't update style span above the input CSS3

Tags: html, css, checkbox, children

Is it possible to update first child after **input**[type=checkbox]:**checked** status in CSS3, without involving jQuery?

My question is about this technique in my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tyxzwp6d/):

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .useraccounts,
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .hashtags {
    background-color: #fd2626; // red color
}
```

Comment: collaboration: http://jsfiddle.net/tyxzwp6d/#&togetherjs=svvTjcn4Mk

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML to your question (click the [edit] link); incidentally the HTML in your posted demo is invalid; `<li>` elements *must* be nested within either a `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Comment: @Paulie_D I disagree.  There are some things you can do to change the content.  You can hide certain elements or you can make use of the `content` rule in a `:before` or `:after` style or change just normal styles of course.  The thing is that we need to know what the OP needs to change.

Comment: You can't select **previous** elements with CSS which seems to be the requirement here.

Comment: You can, however, select elements that come **after**, like the OP mentioned.

Comment: Pending clarification from the OP I'm voting to close as a duplicate (of the same question nominated by Paulie_D); since there's no element following the checkbox elements that have any element-children.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + * {
    color: #fd2626;
}
```

It will select any element that immediately follows the `input` element.